# Sybase database migration from old San storage to new San storage

Tags: database-migration, sybase, database-administration, sap-basis

Any recommendation about Sybase database migration from old San storage to new San storage?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sybase database is independent from hardware. There are no drivers to specific SAN storage systems. If your system works with one vendor and another SAN storage is supported by the operating system it should also work with the database.

There is no need for any migration work while switching to another hardware here.

Answer (score 0):

You basically have various possibilities:

- Take the database server completely offline and migrate the block devices from old SAN to the new SAN. This requires a possible migration path between your old and new SAN. If your old and new SAN are from the same vendor you might have luck and they provide a migration path/tool to do this.
- You leave your database server online and you are providing additional LUNs from the new SAN to your database server. You add those new block devices to your Sybase server and then you setup a disk mirror of the old Sybase device and the new empty once. Once the mirror has synced everything you can remove the old primary device and remove the mirror again so you are able to finally delete the old sybase devices. You can read more about Sybase disk mirroring here: http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.39996_1250/html/svrtsg/svrtsg144.htm
- Another option would be to add new Sybase devices on the new SAN like in step 2 but then create additional empty databases on the new devices. You could then dump and load the databases onto the new databases lying on the new SAN device.

I am sure there are even more possibilities all with different advantages. You will have to figure out what the best way for your environment is. From my personal experience you will have to take the databases sizes and the possible downtime of your server into account for your decision making process.